# How to add customer prefix option in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to add an option for the "prefix" dropdown in "Customer Information > Addresses > Edit Customer's Address"

Where can I add this new value ?

[image]

Comment: Please see the following https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/customers/name-address-options.html for this

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the magento documentation for more info should resolve you issue 
 https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/customers/name-address-options.html